# MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, linker, xamarin.ios-binding

I made a binding from a objective-c framework, it is working correctly but when I try to link my Xamarin.iOS project (Link Framework SDKs Only), I get this error

> MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C
>   class: GLKView. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKView' could not be found
>   in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
>   (MT5211)

[In the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#MT5211), says to add the **[Protocol]** attribute to the binding project.

I tried to add the attribute in the **ApiDefinition.cs**, first on top of the class and then before all methods and interfaces the classe have, with no success.

[Link for the github repo](https://github.com/joaowd/Xamarin.iOS.SinchBind/blob/master/SinchBinding/SinchBinding/ApiDefinition.cs)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you used Objective Sharpie?

Comment: yes I used sharpie

Comment: Have you add the Native Reference?

Comment: to the binding project? yes.

Comment: Is the SDK available from cocoaPod? If you can provide the name of SDK ,I can have a try .

Comment: yes it is, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SinchRTC, thank you lucas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179075/discussion-between-joao-palma-and-lucasz).

Answer (score 1):

I have try the same steps as you did , and downloaded the project you provided.It works on my VS for Mac.So ,I suggest you can creat a new blank bind libaray and copy the code into it then build it again.

I have uploaded my project to my gitHub.you can download it and have a try.
[Demo](https://github.com/MonkeyLucas/bindTest)

Comment: I can give it a try. 2 questions, did you create a new bind or thats the one i created? Also it is possible that when i try to link the error i have is a conflict of nugets?

Comment: Yeah, and I copied the bind project from your solution to my project and now it works. I don't know what to think about this.

Comment: Alright forget it what I just said, it won't give me errors because you didn't had the native reference, so the bind doesn't really work without it. And when I add the native reference I have the same 4 errors that I always had.